# Same offset and partition record is getting consumed twice causing duplicates

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to consume records using application written in spring-kafka. I am facing very unique condition and not able to understand why this is happening ?

My consumer application is running with 2 concurrency meaning 2 consumer thread subscribed to topic having two partitions.I am consuming records and placing it into table using upsert with offset, partitions and insert timestamp.

I am seeing duplicate values with same offset and partition in the table which should not occur. There is no difference in the timestamp value, means insert occurred at the same time. I am not sure how is it possible? I don't see any issue in the log as well. I am not sure what is happening at the Producer end but we can't have 2 values at the same offset anyway, so not sure whether this is an issue at consumer end of producer end.Any suggestion or thought which would help me to triage this issue?

[image]

**Kafka log :**

I don't see anything unusual in the log as well.

```
14:29:56.318 [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.4.0
14:29:56.318 [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 77a89fcf8d7fa018
14:29:56.318 [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1604154596318
14:29:56.319 [main] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Subscribed to topic(s): kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2
14:29:57.914 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Cluster ID: 6cbv7QOaSW6j1vXrOCE4jA
14:29:57.914 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Cluster ID: 6cbv7QOaSW6j1vXrOCE4jA
14:29:57.915 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Discovered group coordinator apslp1563.uhc.com:9093 (id: 2147483574 rack: null)
14:29:57.915 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Discovered group coordinator apslp1563.uhc.com:9093 (id: 2147483574 rack: null)
14:29:57.923 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] (Re-)joining group
14:29:57.924 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] (Re-)joining group
14:29:58.121 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] (Re-)joining group
14:29:58.125 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] (Re-)joining group
14:30:13.127 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Finished assignment for group at generation 23: {consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1-19d92ba5-5dc3-433d-b967-3cf1ce1b4174=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerPartitionAssignor$Assignment@d7e2a1f, consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2-5833c212-7031-4ab1-944b-7e26f7d7a293=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerPartitionAssignor$Assignment@53c3aad3}
14:30:13.131 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Successfully joined group with generation 23
14:30:13.131 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Successfully joined group with generation 23
14:30:13.134 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Adding newly assigned partitions: kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-1
14:30:13.134 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Adding newly assigned partitions: kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-0
14:30:13.143 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-1, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Setting offset for partition kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=500387, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=apslp1559.uhc.com:9093 (id: 69 rack: null), epoch=37}}
14:30:13.143 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-1-C-1] INFO  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-csp-prov-emerald-test-2, groupId=csp-prov-emerald-test] Setting offset for partition kaas.pe.enrollment.csp.ts2-1 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=499503, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=apslp1562.uhc.com:9093 (id: 72 rack: null), epoch=36}}
```

***Code :***

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${app.topic}", groupId = "${app.group_id_config}")
    public void run(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgement) throws Exception {

        try {
                prov_tin_number         = record.value().get("providerTinNumber").toString();
                prov_tin_type           = record.value().get("providerTINType").toString();
                enroll_type             = record.value().get("enrollmentType").toString();
                vcp_prov_choice_ind     = record.value().get("vcpProvChoiceInd").toString();
                error_flag              = "";

                dataexecutor.peStremUpsertTbl(prov_tin_number, prov_tin_type, enroll_type, vcp_prov_choice_ind, error_flag,
                    record.partition(), record.offset());
                
            
                acknowledgement.acknowledge();
                    
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(record);
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: What you. are suggesting should not be possible, unless a rebalance occurred. You can set the container property `commitLogLevel` to INFO to log the offset commits without having to turn on DEBUG logging. That would be my first step to debug it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I couldn't see a trace of rebalancing. That's creating more confusion.

Comment: I wonder why there are so many logs about consumers rejoining the group. Are your consumers running stable or are they being restarted regularly?

Comment: this is not being restarted regularly. Only happening at the start of consumer application.

Comment: Since you getting the same timestamp across records (systimestamp from Oracle), it doesnt look like Kafka problem. Because even if it is consumig it twice the time stamp should have been different. Can you check the code that is writing to database.